# inconsistent date output for svn list command

Tags: svn, date

I am using the svn list command

```
svn list -R -v directory
```

Which produces a listing like this :

```
   2011 user        23339 Jan 22 15:09 path/file.c
   1504 user         7478 Aug 28  2012 path/file.h
```

The problem is when I want to import the data into an excel spreadsheet, `file.c` gets listed as `Jan 22 2015` not  `Jan 22 2013`.

Is there a way of forcing `svn list` to conform to a specific date format, (not with the time preferably) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `svn ls -v` is not designed to be parsed by another program. Use the option `--xml` to get the output in a form that is easy to handle and parse and format it with a script. For example the following Python script parses the output of `svn ls --xml` and prints the *name* and *date* of each file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys, lxml.etree
for entry in lxml.etree.parse(sys.stdin.buffer).iter('entry'):
    get = entry.xpath
    print('{} {}'.format(get('string(name)'), get('string(commit/date)')))
```